# работа с фаилами пользователя через spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee, веб-служба

хочу узнать возможность реализации некой фичи
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку в браузере, то у него должен создаться фаил на компьютере в определенной папке, далее бэк часть должна уметь работать с этим фаилом, т.е. **напрямую** тупо брать фаил и записывать некоторое кол-во строк в фаил.
Естественно фронт с бэком стоят на удаленном сервере.
Использую Angular и Spring Boot.
Возможно ли это реализовать, если да, то что можно почитать на эту тему?

Comment: На машине пользователя должен работать какой-то клиент, который слушает и выполняет команды с сервиса.

Comment: @lampa окай, спасибо, значит эти две стрелки (работа с фаилом) убираем и начинаем работать вперед, назад, через фронт. Хм, а если вебСокет подключить, как вариант?

Comment: фронт не предоставляет возможностей для взаимодействия с машиной пользователя, т.е. через фронт на машине пользователя ничего не создать. Две стрелки обязательно должны быть, т.к. на машине пользователя должен крутиться софт, который умеет взаимодействовать с ОС

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket может решить проблему. Но дело в вашем фронтенде, видимо это браузер. У браузера в целях безопасности нет доступа к файловой системе, вы не можете читать, создавать или редактировать файлы пользователя. Для решения данной проблемы нужно нативное приложение на стороне клиента, это единственное решение.